# DataGridViewComboBoxCell Value not being set properly

Tags: c#

I've been trying to set the value of an individual DataGridViewComboBoxCell for the last 4 hours and I've been getting nowhere. The most common solution I've seen was to set the .Value member of the DataGridViewComboBoxCell to one of the Items, which I tried and it complained the value was not valid.

```
DataTable documentTypes = _codedValues.GetCodedValues(Database.DOCUMENT_TYPE_TABLE);                documentTypes.Columns[Database.PROFESSION_ID_COLUMN].AllowDBNull = true;
documentTypes.Columns[Database.CODE].AllowDBNull = true;
this.cbxDocumentType.DisplayMember = Database.VALUE;
this.cbxDocumentType.ValueMember = Database.CODE;
this.cbxDocumentType.DataSource = documentTypes.DefaultView;
int rowId = this.dgvDocumentList.Rows.Add(doc.actualName, doc.fileName);
DataGridViewComboBoxCell obj = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)this.dgvDocumentList.Rows[rowId].Cells[2];
obj.Value = obj.Items[0];
```

After the message box comes up that tells me DataGridViewComboBoxCell view is not valid, I see the .ToString output of the object being set, which is System.Data.DataRowValue.

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Answer (score 0):

Depending what your datasource contains you must use the correct casts to access the correct fields.

Try this:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = 
                      (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)this.dgvDocumentList.Rows[rowId].Cells[2];
cell.Value = ((DataRowView)cell.Items[0]).Row.ItemArray[0];
```

This assumes that the `Items` are `DataRowViews` and that the `ValueMember` is in the first field.

You can test the type by writing an intermediate step:

```
var item = cell.Items[0];
```

And use the debugger to look into the resulting type..